# javascript regex parsing array-syntax strings almost working

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, url

So I'm parsing strings (from a URL) that have an array-like syntax, such as:

```
variable[foo]
variable[foo][bar]
```

I need EACH of the indexes (in square brackets) to be it's own capturing group, and I need it to work with one OR MORE indexes... My regex ALMOST works, but only captures the FINAL index, not the proceeding ones, so works perfect with one index.

[here](http://regexr.com/3g64k) you can see my best attempt, and when you hover over the second example, you'll see that group_4 becomes captured group #2 and the rest are lost.  I need the captured groups to match the example names.

Just for good measure, here you can see my whole solution for parsing the regex results into actual javascript objects.

```
getUrlParams: function() {
        let query = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);

        let paramRegex = /[&?]([\w[\]\-%]+)=([\w[\]\-%/,\s]+)(?=&|$)/igm;
        let arrayRegex = /([\w]+)(?:(?:\[|%5B)([\w]+)(?:]|%5D))+/igm;

        let params = {};

        let match = paramRegex.exec(query);
        while (match !== null) {
            if (match && match[1]) {

                let array = arrayRegex.exec(match[1]);
                while(array !== null) {
                    if (array && array[1] && array[2]) {
                        console.log("ARRAY: ", array);
                         let deepParam = {};
                         deepParam[array[2]] = match[2];
                         if (array[1] in params) {
                             $.extend(params[array[1]], deepParam);
                         } else {
                             params[array[1]] = deepParam;
                         }
                    } else {
                        params[match[1]] = match[2];
                    }

                    array = arrayRegex.exec(match[1]);
                }
            }
            match = paramRegex.exec(query);
        }
        return params;
    },
```

This code works great with only one index, but once the regex captures multiple indexes, this code will have to handle it too.

Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here is my final function solution, based on bowheart's very elegant code.

```
    getUrlParams: function() {
    let query = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
    let paramRegex = /[&?]([\w[\]\-%]+)=([\w[\]\-%/,\s]+)(?=&|$)/igm;

    let params = {};

    let match = paramRegex.exec(query);
    while (match !== null) {
        if (match && match[1] && match[2]) {
            let key = match[1];
            let val = match[2];
            let arrayKeys = key.split(/\[|]/g).filter(node => node);
            populateObject(params, arrayKeys, val);

        }
        match = paramRegex.exec(query);
    }

    return params;

    function populateObject(obj, keys, val) {
        if (keys.length === 1) return obj[keys[0]] = (isNaN(+val) ? val : +val);
        let nextKey = keys.shift();
        if (!obj[nextKey]) obj[nextKey] = isNaN(+keys[0]) ? {} : [];

        populateObject(obj[nextKey], keys, val);
    }
},
```

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare.  I see Regex and run lol.  Any chance you can modify you query string?  My guess is you are passing these as params to hit some API or something of the sort.  Why not pass an object with the values already parsed out? Stop the problem before it becomes one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What on earth gave you the idea to accomplish all this with two massive regular expressions? Just...Don't do that. You'll probably live longer. You will need regex to some degree, but always keep it as short as possible.

Here's a solution, if you're interested. You'll notice it's shorter, much easier to read, and accomplishes all the requirements:

```js
// Recursively populates nested objects/arrays.
function populateObj(obj, keys, val) {
    if (keys.length === 1) return obj[keys[0]] = val

    let nextKey = keys.shift()
    if (!obj[nextKey]) obj[nextKey] = isNaN(+keys[0]) ? {} : []

    populateObj(obj[nextKey], keys, val)
}

let params = {}
let search = '?filters[name]=sa&filters[group_2][group_3][group_4]=4&order_bys[0][field]=name&order_bys=desc'

search.slice(1).split('&').forEach(pair => {
    let [key, val] = pair.split('=')
    key = key.split(/\[|]/g).filter(node => node)
    populateObj(params, key, val)
})

// Just for display:
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(params, null, ' &nbsp;').replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
```

The basic algorithm is:

- Split the GET params on `'&'`, then split each param into a key-val pair on `'='`.
- Regex out any square brackets in the keys to get all nodes for nested arrays/objects.
- Recursively traverse an object, creating child objects/arrays when necessary, and assign the given value to the last node.

  - Create an array if the next key is numeric. Otherwise, create an object.

(Note from your regexr snippet that `order_bys[0][field]=name` and `order_bys=desc` params are incompatible as one indicates that `order_bys` is a zero-indexed array and the other that it's a string. Not sure where you got that data...).

Comment: That is a beautiful solution.  Though I did keep the first regex in my solution, because my values can have & in them which would throw off the simple split.  I'm updating the question to show my final solution, which I think works perfectly to extract any and all variables from the url and create them as proper objects/arrays.

Comment: The only thing I'm confused about in this solution, is what does this "node => node" do in the filter() parameters?

Comment: And I added a ternary in the populateObject function to make sure the value is set to a number, not a string if it's numeric.

Comment: @JoshuaChambers `array.filter(x => x)` is something you'll see a lot. It just filters out falsy values from the array. And good, this solution of course doesn't cover every use case. A more robust solution would keep `search` as a normal, encoded uri string and it would only decode the `key` and `val` individually after splitting. This would keep any `&` and `=` characters in the keys or values themselves as encoded url characters (`%26` and `%3D`) until after the regex does its thing. And yep, you can beef up the type parsing as much as you want. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(?:[\?|\&]([\w]+))|((?:\[|%5B)(\w+)(?:]|%5D))
```

It captures each group value as an independent match

Comment: This is indeed a regex that solves the part of the problem I was mostly asking about, and this answer really helped me to understand the difference between multiple matches to a regex, and multiple capture groups in one match of a regex.  Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could provide any help in any form

Answer (score 0):

Split on square brackets and filter out empty strings:

```
"variable[foo][bar]".split(/\]|\[/).filter(s => !!s)
> [ "variable", "foo", "bar" ]
```